# Answering your own review

Tags: discussion, self-answer

As a piece of code is subjected to peer review, the author should also be looking at ways to improve his code. Sometimes a problem pointed out by others will direct his attention to another issue in the code. On Code Review, should he edit that suggestion/edit into his question (as an edit to keep continuity), or should he submit it as an answer?

Comment: [This](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/752/is-it-okay-to-edit-parts-of-code-not-yet-reviewed/753#753) might be relevant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I answer my own question with the improved code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/should-i-answer-my-own-question-with-the-improved-code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think he should post it as an answer unless it was a very minor thing, then reference the person who indirectly brought it up. If it was a minor thing, he should probably just comment on the person's answer and update my question.

I would imagine either way would work, though.

Answer (score 5):

I think answer will be better, as significant question edits might be disruptive to others who already answered.

(trivial or minor question edits are of course always ok)